# Are there any non-gauge invariant physical theories that describe anything from the "real world"?

Tags: gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I have learnt QFT and the Standard Model and we always had gauge invariance there (in my lectures at least...) I wonder if there are any theories which are not gauge invariant that describe a bit of "reality"?

I have read this post [Can we allowe gauge non-invariant terms in a gauge theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/302447/) and this one [What is the problem with a Lagrangian that isn't gauge invariant?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328861/) but I could not find a definite answer to my question.

I have also read that the superconducting phase transition breaks $U(1)$ gauge symmetry, but I don't fully understand that bit, it doesn't appear to me a superconducting phase is described by a non gauge invariant Lagrangian, or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

I published a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078) describing a working non-gauge invariant theory of  classical electromagnetism, thereby breaking [the spell of the gauge principle](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/1948). In this approach it is explicit that the Lorentz force only accounts for the change in kinetic momentum of a charge. However, a charge also has *potential* momentum and only the sum of the two is conserved. It also accounts for spin as a separately conserved contribution to angular momentum, something impossible in gauge theory. The Lorenz condition is interpreted as a consequence of charge conservation. It is still possible to add a "gauge" field to the potential without altering the charge kinetic (Lorentz) force. However, such solutions correspond to *nonconserved* source distributions that give the same field tensor as the original one.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will read your paper tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

The forces between nucleons can be described in an *low-energy effective field theory* that gives a good low-energy description of QCD. In this theory, the charged and neutral pions (which are scalar fields) mediate interactions between nucleons (which are fermions). There are no gauge fields.

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to look this up. I haven't learnt QCD in detail yet, but now I'm even more curious.

Comment: But pions are pseudo-Goldstone bosons. Yukawa's original theory was an SU(2) gauge theory, at least according to "An Elementary Primer on Gauge Theory" by K Moriyasu [World Scientific, 1983].

Comment: @lawliet There's a primer here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.3229.pdf#:~:text=Chiral%20perturbation%20theory%20(ChPT)%20is,systematic%20and%20model%20independent%20way..

Comment: @JEB Sure. But the pions appear as (pseudo)scalars in the EFT. You don't need to include any gauge fields, if you just want to describe interactions mediated by pions.